# Vaadin table cell is being called twice

Tags: java, gwt, vaadin

I use vaadin generated columns in my table. While debugging I noticed that the method

```
 generateCell(Table source, Object itemId, Object columnId)
```

is being called twice for each cell to be created. I don't know if this is normal,but does not make sense, It shows OK but then it will take twice longer to load the table. I checked if I do  somewhere an errornous refresh or repaint but no I couldn't find.

I create my column generator a bit different;

```
table.addGeneratedColumn("name of column", new myNewColumnGenerator ());
```

and then this class will be called

```
public class myNewColumnGenerator implements Table.ColumnGenerator {

    public Object generateCell(Table source, Object itemId, Object columnId) {
     //Here this method called twice for each itemId in this column
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you double check your code? I have just did similar thing (used inline anonymous class instead of dedicated class) and it is called only once per cell. Used Vaadin 6.8.0.

Comment: @Sorrow I didnt used inline anonymous class

Comment: I checked also with your approach (just to make sure). Still, method gets called only once. Please check whether you have the column added twice, for example, or the table being created twice. Also, please provide a little more code and your Vaadin version.

Comment: Create a Map that caches those generated cells, so when the the generate method is called again, return it from the map.